# Another way for fill a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, fill

Why does it work? Could explain me how and why, please!

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
    {
        add("one");
        add("two");
        add("three");
    }
};

for ( String element : list )
    System.out.println(element);
```

Comment: @Jigar  Joshi, that was fast lol

Comment: Write this code in IDE and play around. See where do we have add() implementation ...

Answer (score 1):

This means you created a class extending the `arraylist` and added a static block.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(){};  // At this step you have created an instance of an anonymus class assigned to the list varibale

new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
        add("one");
        add("two");
        add("three");
        } // This is a static block inside your newly created anonymus class. 
};
```